# How to Enable NFC on Android Nexus s emulator

Tags: driver, emulation, nfc

I have Installed Android Nexus S emulator on my linux machine, as well as my Windows machine. 
While opening the NFC tag on emulator I am receiving the error: 'NFC is not supported'. As I am developing an application on NFC, I need to have NFC support on my emulator. What else do I need to do to make this work?

This will be very helpful if anyone can share ideas on this problem

Answer (score 0):

the best way to deal with NFC is use the real phone - this is same with all HW features on mobile phones (camera, GPS, etc)...

BR
STeN